# C++ should I use templates, I'm about to create a lexer, why should it be limited chars?

Tags: c++, c, templates, c++11

I'm about to create a lexer for a project, proof of concepts of it exists, the idea works and whatnot, I was about to start writing it and I realised:

Why chars?

(I'm moving away from C, I'm still fairly suspicious of the standard libraries, I felt it easier to deal in char* for offsets and such than learn about strings)

why not w_char or something, ints, or indeed any type (given it has some defined operations).

So should I use a template? So far it seems like yes I should but there are 2 counter-arguments I can consider:

Firstly, modular complication, the moment I write "template" it must go in a header file / be available with implementation to whatever uses it (it's not a matter of hiding source code I don't mind the having to show code part, it will be free (as in freedom) software) this means extra parsing and things like that.

My C background screams not to do this, I seem to want separate .o files, I understand why I can't by the way, I'm not asking for a way. 
Separate object files speed up complication, because the make file (you tell it or have it use -MM with the compiler to figure out for itself) wont run the complication command for things that haven't changed and so forth.

Secondly, with templates, I know of no way to specify what a type must do, other than have the user realise when something fails (you know how Java has an extends keyword) I suspect that C++11 builds on this, as meta-programming is a large chapter in "The C++ programming language" 4th edition.

Are these reasons important these days? I learned with the following burned into my mind:
"You are not creating one huge code file that gets compiled, you create little ones that are linked" and templates seem to go against this.

I'm sure G++ parses very quickly, but it also optimises, if it spends a lot of time optimising one file, it'll re-do that optimisation every time it sees that in a translation unit, where as with separate object files, it does a bit (general optimisations) only once, and perhaps a bit more if you use LTO (link time optimisation)

Or I could create a class that every input to the lexer derives from and use that (generic programming I believe it's called) but my C-roots say "eww virtuals" and urge me towards the char*

I understand this is quite open, I just don't know where to draw the line between using a template, and not using a template.

Comment: This question is waaaay too long

Comment: Opinion: Try to be guided by practical concerns. I recently wrote a templated lexer with the intention of allowing the user to instantiate it with either char* or istream_iterator. As I needed > 1 char lookahead the istream_iterator option was excluded. The lexer is now a straight char based lexer. If you can't think of a use case for a templated version right now, go with the char* one.

Comment: Make a typedef for char and it should be easy to change to a template later on if you need to.

Comment: @NeilKirk but then you can't have lexers of different types in the same program, I had thought of that, also my C roots say define something then include a file that uses the defined constant, but that is not the C++ way.

Comment: Why not use something like Flex - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser - might save a lot of effort on your part.

Comment: @EdHeal I actually know (AND LOVE) Flex and Bison, the two work superbly with each other and in this case the lexer may be implemented by something that uses Flex, unfortunately more complex grammars require more than what Flex and Bison can offer, this is what I am doing

Answer (score 4):

Templates don't have to be in the header! If you have only a few instantiations, you can explicitly instantiate the class and function templates in suitable translation units. That is, a template would be split into three parts:

1. A header declaring the templates.
2. A header including the first and implementing the template but otherwise only included in the third set of files.
3. Source files including the headers in 2. and explicitly instantiating the templates with the corresponding types.

Users of these template would only include the header and never the implementation header. An example where this can be done are IOStreams: There are basically just two instantiations: one for `char` and one for `wchar_t`. Yes, you can instantiate the streams for other types but I doubt that anybody would do so (I'm sometimes questioning if anybody uses stream with a different character type than `char` but probably people are).

That said, the concepts used by templates are, indeed, not explicitly represented in the source and C++11 doesn't add any facilities to do so either. There were discussions on adding *concepts* to C++ but so far they are not part of any standard. There is a *concepts light* proposal which, I think, will be included in C++14.

However, in practice I haven't found that much of a problem: it is quite possible to document the concepts and use things like `static_assert()` to potentially produce nicer error messages. The problem is more that many concepts are actually more restrictive than the underlying algorithms and that the extra slack is sometimes quite useful.

Here is a brief and somewhat made-up example of how to implement and instantiate the template. The idea is to implement something like `std::basic_ostream` but merely provide out scaled-down version of a string output operator:

```
// simple-ostream.hpp
#include "simple-streambuf.hpp"
template <typename CT>
class simple_ostream {
     simple_streambuf<CT>* d_sbuf;
public:
     simple_ostream(simple_streambuf<CT>* sbuf);
     simple_streambuf<CT>* rdbuf() { return this->d_sbuf; } // should be inline
};
template <typename CT>
simple_ostream<CT>& operator<< (simple_ostream<CT>&, CT const*);
```

Except for the `rdbuf()` member the above is merely a class definition with a few member declarations and a function declaration. The `rdbuf()` function is implemented directly to show that you can mix&match the visible implementation where performance is necessary with external implementation where decoupling is more important. The used class template `simple_streambuf` is thought to be similar to `std::basic_streambuf` and, at least, declared in the header `"simple-streambuf.hpp"`.

```
// simple-ostream.tpp
// the implementation, only included to create explicit instantiations
#include "simple-ostream.hpp"

template <typename CT>
simple_ostream<CT>::simple_ostream(simple_streambuf<CT>* sbuf): d_sbuf(sbuf) {}

template <typename CT>
simple_ostream<CT>& operator<< (simple_ostream<CT>& out, CT const* str) {
    for (; *str; ++str) {
        out.rdbuf()->sputc(*str);
    }
    return out;
}
```

This implementation header is only included when explicitly instantiating the class and function templates. For example, to instantiations for `char` would look like this:

```
// simple-ostream-char.cpp
#include "simple-ostream.tpp"

// instantiate all class members for simple_ostream<char>:
template class simple_ostream<char>;
// instantiate the free-standing operator
template simple_ostream<char>& operator<< <char>(simple_ostream<char>&, char const*);
```

Any use of the `simple_ostream<CT>` would just include `simple-ostream.hpp`. For example:

```
// use-simple-ostream.cpp
#include "simple-ostream.hpp"

int main()
{
    simple_streambuf<char> sbuf;
    simple_ostream<char>   out(&sbuf);
    out << "hello, world\n";
}
```

Of course, to build an executable you will need both `use-simple-ostream.o` and `simple-ostream-char.o` but assuming the template instantiations are part of a library this isn't really adding any complexity. The only real headache is when a user wants to use the class template with unexpected instantiations, say, `char16_t`, but only `char` and `wchar_t` are provided: In this case the user would need to explicitly create the instantiations or, if necessary, include the implementation header.

In case you want to try the example out, below is a somewhat simple-minded and sloppy (because being header-only) implementation of `simple-streambuf<CT>`:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_SIMPLE_STREAMBUF
#define INCLUDED_SIMPLE_STREAMBUF
#include <iostream>

template <typename CT> struct stream;
template <>
struct stream<char> {
    static std::ostream& get() { return std::cout; }
};
template <>
struct stream<wchar_t> {
    static std::wostream& get() { return std::wcout; }
};

template <typename CT>
struct simple_streambuf
{
    void sputc(CT c) {
        stream<CT>::get().rdbuf()->sputc(c);
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Could you provide a short example, also when it comes to instantiating the templates with parameters is there a nice way to do that, or just copy and paste find and replace? I think you are suggesting that I write everything out in template form, but instantiate that template in say char in a specific header, then include that header elsewhere? I'm not quite sure how I'd do that sorry.

Comment: @AlecTeal: I added a working example (well, you'll need to split the code into files and build it). However, it should compile and link without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be limited to chars. Why ? Because you're asking...

I have little experience with templates, but when I used templates the necessity arose naturally, I didn't need *to try* to use templates.

My 2 cents, FWIW.

Comment: So the gist is: You have no desire to use it for anything other than chars so why add the ability to?

Comment: @AlecTeal your question was way to long to actually read, but I disagree with this guy, most classes are easy to make generic with templates, if you want to learn c++ do it, they make code more reusable

Comment: @aaronman but then as the question states, the entire lexer would be included every time it is needed, implementation and all because it is a template, this goes against what I have always clung to - modular complication. The question is long because the goblins in my mind are bickering about it, I just typed it out.

Comment: @Alec Teal: basically, yes. But there's something else to consider: the level of expertise. My level of expertise with templates is low, so I tend not to use them, unless they literally cry to be used.

Comment: This would be my answer too, because starting with a template (instead of extracting it later from parallel variants) has a cost but  the resulting flexibility isn't useful. 

However, the argument is for committing to a single appropriate character type, and I don't think **char** is the right choice: the vast majority of characters cannot be represented adequately, I would use 32 bit unsigned integers with general Unicode decoding shielding the lexer from the complications of text file formats.

Answer (score 0):

> 1: Firstly, modular complication, the moment I write "template" it must go in a header file…

That's not a real argument. You have the ability to use C, C++, structs, classes, templates, classes with virtual functions, and all the other benefits of a multi paradigm language. You're not coerced to take an all-or-nothing approach with your designs, and you can mix and match these functionalities based on your design's needs. So you can use templates where they are an appropriate tool, and other constructs where templates are not ideal. It's hard to know when that will be, until after you have had experience using them all. Template/header-only libraries are popular, but one of the reasons the approach is used is that they simplify linking and the build process, and can reduce dependencies if designed well. If they are designed poorly, then yes, they can result in an explosion in compile times. That's not the language's fault -- it's the implementor's design.

Heck, you could even put your implementations behind C opaque types and use templates for everything, keeping the core template code visible to exactly one translation.

> 2: Secondly, with templates, I know of no way to specify what a type must do…

That is generally regarded as a feature. Instantiation can result in further instantiations which is capable of instantiating different implementations and specializations -- this is template meta programming domain. Often, all you really need to do is instantiate the implementation, which results in evaluation of the type and parameters. This -- simulation of "concepts" and interface verification -- can increase your build times, however. But furthermore, that may not be the best design because deferring instantiation is in many cases preferable.

If you just need to brute-force instantiate all your variants, one approach would be to create a separate translation which does just that -- you don't even need to link it to your library; add it to a unit test or some separate target. That way, you could validate instantiation and functionalities are correct without significant impact to your clients including/linking to the library.

> Are these reasons important these days?

No. Build times are of course very important, but I think you just need to learn the right tool to use, and when and why some implementations must be abstracted (or put behind compilation firewalls) when/if you need fast builds and scalability for large projects. So yes, they are important, but a good design can strike a good balance between versatility and build times. Also remember that template metaprogramming is capable of moving a significant amount of program validation from runtime to compile time. So a hit on compile times does not have to be bad, because it can save you from a lot of runtime validations/issues.

> I'm sure G++ parses very quickly, but it also optimises, if it spends a lot of time optimising one file, it'll re-do that optimisation every time it sees that in a translation unit…

Right; That redundancy can kill fast build times.

> where as with separate object files, it does a bit (general optimisations) only once, and perhaps a bit more if you use LTO (link time optimisation) … Separate object files speed up complication, because the make file (you tell it or have it use -MM with the compiler to figure out for itself) wont run the complication command for things that haven't changed and so forth.

Not necessarily so. First, many object files produce a lot of demand on the linker. Second, it multiplies the work because you have more translations, so reducing object files is a good thing. This really depends on the structure of your libraries and dependencies. Some teams take the approach the opposite direction (I do quite regularly), and use an approach which produces few object files. This can make your builds many times faster with complex projects because you eliminate redundant work for the compiler and linker. For best results, you need a good understanding of the process and your dependencies. In large projects, translation/object reductions can result in builds which are many times faster. This is often referred to as a "Unity Build". Large Scale C++ Design by John Lakos is a great read on dependencies and C++ project structures, although it's rather dated at this point so you should not take every bit of advice at face value.

So the short answer is: Use the best tool for the problem at hand -- a good designer will use many available tools. You're far from exhausting the capabilities of the tools and build systems. A good understanding of these subjects will take years.